# What is the correct validation pattern for accepting numbers more than 0 in HTML 5?

Tags: html

I am trying to use text input (not number) to do number validation for a condition of more than 0.
So, it should not accept inputs -1, -2, 0. But 1, 100, 2000, 4000000.. possibly do a limit on it.

Is there a pattern to do something like that using HTML5 validation ? (not js/jq just HTML5 validation)

Here is what I tried but does not fulfill completely my requirements:

- this works perfectly but I dont want to use number type but "text"

http://jsfiddle.net/5Krwy/

```
<input id="quantity" name="quantity" type="number" min="1" max="100000" required />
```

- now this uses the type text I want, but it can still accept 0. How to improve on this pattern ?

http://jsfiddle.net/5Krwy/1/

```
<input id="quantity" name="quantity" type="text" pattern = "[0-9]{1,5}" required />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make type="number" to positive numbers only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233415/how-to-make-type-number-to-positive-numbers-only)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<input id="quantity" name="quantity" type="text" pattern = "[1-9][0-9]{0,4}" required />
```

Answer (score 1):

obviously, you should change the `patten` attribute

```
<input id="quantity" name="quantity" type="text" pattern = "[1-9]{1,5}" required />
```

Comment: This would prevent entry of the number 10.

Comment: `"[1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,4}"/>`

Comment: @YubinDuan, Update your answer so it will let me remove the down vote.