# Is there a way to suppress scientific notation for <input type="number">?

Tags: html, floating-point, html-input, scientific-notation

I'd like to input numbers with up to eight decimal points with an `<input>` element. However, if I have an `<input type="number" step="0.00000001">` and use the up/down arrows on the input element (on Chrome; here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zve5hw0c/)), then I get scientific notation for the small numbers:

[image]

If I input, say, 5, and then hit the arrow key, then scientific notation is suppressed:

[image]

Is there any way to get the browser to display the `1e-8` as `0.000000001`?

Also, is there any danger here that with sufficiently small numbers, I'll hit floating point rounding errors?

```html
<input type="number" step="0.00000001">
```

Comment: Worth to mention that a number will not always be displayed in scientific notation. This answer explains when this will happen: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46231666/11298742

Answer (score 12):

```html
<input oninput='precise(this)' type="number" step="0.00000001">

<script>
  function precise(elem) {
    elem.value = Number(elem.value).toFixed(8);
  }
</script>
```

You can change the [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) parameter to the desired number of decimal digits as needed. I hope this helps!

Comment: you can pass the specific `input` element with `oninput=precise(this)`, then doing `function precise(el) { el.value = Number(el.value).toFixed(8); }`

Answer (score 5):

Here is a variation based on StardustGogeta's [answer](http://#answer-36755620):

```
<input oninput="this.value=Number(this.value).toFixed(this.step.split('.')[1].length)" type=number step="0.00000001">
```

Comment: When you bind to `oninput` it works when you click the arrows next to the input field, but it doesn't let you type. If you replace `oninput` with `onclick` it lets you type and only modifies the content if you use the arrows.