# Angular 2 - accept only natural number in input

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a shop component and I need to disallow people to pick negative numbers in my input.

For example, if user will type **-3** in my input, the input value will immadiately change to **0**.

How I can control my angular 2 input **OnChange** value to set it back to **0** it the value is negative?

Tried to use `(ngModelChange)="myMethod($event)"` and set the parameter to 0 if it's negative, but didn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Use `min` and `step` to prevent the spinner from going negative. (reference: [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19233458/215945))
- Use `ngModelChange` to handle the case where a user tries to type in a negative number.

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `{{title}}
    <p><input type="number" min="0" step="1" [ngModel]="model"
        (ngModelChange)="validate($event)">`,
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = `Angular - RC.1`;
  model = 3;
  validate(value)  {
    value < 0 ? this.model = 0 : this.model = value;
  }
}
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jERgNOa7OCm1TeiRPCrw?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you, but how I can know on the `validate` method which model im working on, if I'm looping on a list of items? `[(ngModel)]="items[i].amount"`

Comment: Why is the validate method triggered twice when clicking the up/down buttons?

Comment: @TheUnreal, pass `i` in the method call:  `validate($event, i)`, then lookup the element in the method.

Comment: @tdhulster, good question... I don't know why.  It also happens if you use the up/down arrow keys.

Comment: @tdhulster, maybe it is triggered twice because you are not in prod mode...
("Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode." is gonna be shown in the console)

Answer (score 0):

Using the `min` and `digits` validators from the module [ng2-validation](https://github.com/yuyang041060120/ng2-validation) would do the trick for you.