# Custom validation for positive numbers

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I was trying to find the information, if there are any built-in validators, that check if the input is a positive number?

I was trying to build the following:

```
static nonZero(control:Control) {
    if (Number(control.value) < 0) {
        control.setErrors({nonZero: true})
    } else {
    control.setErrors(null)
    }
}
```

However, I didn't know how to use it in my form builder:

```
this.form = _formBuilder.group({
            field:['', Validators.required]})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may want to check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233415/how-to-make-type-number-to-positive-numbers-only/19233458) too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can configure it this way by leveraging the `Validators.compose` method:

```
this.form = _formBuilder.group({
        field:['', Validators.compose([
                     Validators.required, nonZero ])
        ]});
```

This allows you to define your two synchronous validators for the field.

**Edit**

I would implement the validator this way:

```
static nonZero(control:Control):{ [key: string]: any; } {
  if (Number(control.value) < 0) {
    return {nonZero: true};
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, this throws me the following error: Argument of type '((control: Control) => void)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ValidatorFn[]'.
  Type '(control: Control) => void' is not assignable to type 'ValidatorFn'.
    Type 'void' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: any; }'.

Comment: In fact, I would implement the validator a bit differently. I updated my answer...

Answer (score 7):

You can also use the built-in validator min with Number.MIN_VALUE to accept every positive value.

For example:

```
this.form = _formBuilder.group({
    field:['', [Validators.required, Validators.min(Number.MIN_VALUE)]]
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Little refactored:

```
 export function positiveNumberValidator(): ValidatorFn {
      return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {
        const isNotOk = Number(control.value) < 0;
        return isNotOk ? { nonPositive: { value: control.value } } : null;
      };
 }
```

and if you want to use it in template as `Directive`:

```
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ValidatorFn, AbstractControl, NG_VALIDATORS, Validator } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[prePositiveNumber]',
  providers: [{ provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: PositiveNumberDirective, multi: true }]

})
export class PositiveNumberDirective implements Validator {

  validate(c: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any; } {
    return positiveNumberValidator()(c);
  }
}

export function positiveNumberValidator(): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {
    const isNotOk = Number(control.value) < 0;
    return isNotOk ? { nonPositive: { value: control.value } } : null;
  };
}
```

**Template:**

```
 <input type="number"
        class="full"
        name="shipmentVolume"
        required
        prePositiveNumber
        [(ngModel)]="someModel" />
```

When using as `Reactive forms` you can `compose` validators, but also it can be used without `compose`:

```
this.form = _formBuilder.group({
        field:['', Validators.required, positiveNumberValidator()] });
```

Comment: As far as I know, positive number should not include zero.

Answer (score 3):

You can combine min Validator and a regex pattern Validator:

```
 field: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.min(1), Validators.pattern('^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$')]],
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like,

**.js**

```
  orderFormGroup = new FormGroup({
    weight: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.min(0)])
  });
```

This would allow less than and **equal** to zero values, if you want values more than zero then you could mention `Validators.min(0.1)`

**.html**

```
  <input type="number" step="0.1" name="orderWeight" formControlName="weight" max="35" min="0" class="clr-input form-control">
```

Note that the `min="0"` would only ensure that the front-end increase or decrease wouldnt go passed 0. The actual input validation is handled in .js

Answer (score 0):

I'd use same compose methodology, but implement a min function, that you can pass 1 too.

```
import { ValidatorFn, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
export function min(min: Number): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} => {
      const input = control.value,
            isValid = input < min;
      if(isValid) 
          return { 'minValue': {min} }
      else 
          return null;
    };
}
```

```
this.pnFG = this.fb.group({
  pageNumberInput: [this.pageNumber, 
                    Validators.compose([
                        Validators.required,
                        min(1)
                    ])
                  ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution that requires no additional code

```
[Validators.required, Validators.min(1 / Number.MAX_VALUE)]
```

the solution with validator that return error object that is equivalent to Validators.min, so the error message is handled appropriately

```
export function positiveNumberValidator(control: AbstractControl): { min: { min: number, actual: string | number } } {
  const value = parseFloat(control.value);
  const isValid = !isNaN(value) && value > 0;
  if (isValid) {
    return null;
  }
  return { min: { min: 0, actual: value ?? '' } };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="number" ng-model="size" name="size" min="0" max="10" integer />
```

Easy as that!

Comment: Hey @user3564943 - Could you maybe add onto your answer to elaborate? Also, is this the integer directive you're using? https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-integer