# How to check negative values on text box in angular 6 using form control

Tags: django, angular

```
component.ts

 this.companySettingsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    'delivary_charge': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, ])],  
     });
     this.delivary_charge = this.companySettingsForm.controls['delivary_charge'];
  }
```

> In Component.html i added min and max values, but it won't work

```
component.html

<input pInputText #value type="number" [formControl]="surcharge" min="1" 
max="9999999999999" class="input-width">
```

Comment: you're using ReactiveForms, use Validators.compose([Validators.required,Validators.min(0)])

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38098822/custom-validation-for-positive-numbers

Answer (score 0):

You can set the min and max length of your form control using [`Validators.minLength()`](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#minlength) and [`Validators.maxLength()`](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#maxlength) in your form control.

To check negative values you can use [`Validators.min()`](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#min)

```
this.companySettingsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    'delivary_charge': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(10), Validators.min(0)])],  
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also restrict/check negative values in your component.ts like this

```
myControl:FormControl = new FormControl();
this.myControl.valueChanges.subscribe(val=>{
  if(val<0){
    // you can check negative values here and do whatever you'd like
    // you can also set the value of your input to null or 0 to prevent negative values 
    // this.myControl.setValue(null);
  }
 });
```

Comment: Angular can perform the work for you, Why not take advantage of it?

Comment: As far as i know, Validators.min(0) will not validate the form if the value is lesse than 0. What i'm suggesting is to not allow the users to type a value lesser than 0 and try to submit it.