# Filter input text only accept number and dot vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I have a text box and only want to accept numbers and a period "." when using VueJS. Can anyone help with code? I'm new to Vue.

Comment: I know its an old question but it was top in Google results. So here is a solution to users with similar problem. I think all solutions here are complicated. The simplest thing to do is to add @input event and replace all non-digits and dot. `this.message.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,'');`. Here is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2c7h4qsm/1/)** to demonstrate.

Comment: @KalimahApps - allows for multiple dots = problem.

Comment: Seriously, don't read further do what @Kalimah suggests.  I had it enabled in 15 secs

Comment: @Kalimah I really like your solution. That's what I did firstly, but the problem is when I have multiple text fields which accept only numbers. How can I do it without repeating code? I made one function that worked for all fields using using `event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");` on "@input" event, but when I added v-model (because I need it for different reason), now it doesn't work... Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @VasilijeBursac You can use this [codepen](https://codepen.io/aliso1990/pen/eYzdQXy).

Comment: @AliSohrabi Thank you very much for answer and help!

Answer (score 111):

You can write a Vue method and that method can be called on the *keypress* event. Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gargdeendayal/4qqza69k/).

Update:

adding source code:

#### HTML

```html
<div id="demo">
  <input v-model="message" @keypress="isNumber($event)">
</div>
```

#### Vue.js

```js
var data = {
  message: 1234.34
}

var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: data,
  methods: {
    isNumber: function(evt) {
      evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
      var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
      if ((charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) && charCode !== 46) {
        evt.preventDefault();;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Like what? Did you check the fiddle?

Comment: i still can input character like a, b, c

Comment: @MuhGhazaliAkbar, How? I can't seem to type anything.

Comment: @MuhGhazaliAkbar  Did you try the fiddle ? I can type and see that it only allows number and dot.

Comment: In order to not allow the period change `charCode !== 46` to `charCode === 46`

Comment: In order to make it work in Firefox replace `isNumber(event)` to `isNumber`

Comment: I implemented this and it works well except for one thing. I had to define event in data or it would throw a console error. I simply added "event: null" and no more errors!

Comment: Actually the binding should be `v-on:keypress="isNumber($event)"`

Comment: What part should I change to avoid points? I just need numbers

Comment: This doesn't work at all in Firefox. It also shows the console warning. Replacing isNumber(event) with isNumber($event) as tanathos suggested fixes both problems and works in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: I tried in in your js fiddle, and I can input more than 1 period. It must be 1 only. How to do that?

Comment: How this handle paste?

Comment: This does not handle pasting random string.

Comment: You better use the following function for VUE JS: ```isNumber(evt) {
      evt = evt || window.event;
      let charCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode;
      if (
        charCode > 31 &&
        (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) &&
        charCode !== 46
      ) {
        evt.preventDefault();
      } else {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }```

Comment: how to only allow one dot only

Comment: My solution is more flexible since it's based on `input` event and therefore it handles paste events as well. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64974337/836723

Answer (score 53):

You should change your input to `type="number"` to more accurately reflect your behaviour. You can then use the built-in Vue.js directive `v-model.number`.

Usage:

```
<input type="number" v-model.number="data.myNumberData"/>
```

Comment: Some browsers have `onScroll` for `type=number`, which increment/decrement values.

Comment: Using `type=number` is not always a good solution for numerical input as the browser will style the input box differently and add increment/decrement buttons.

Comment: this answer work but only one character (E) is allowing to enter. why any reason?

Comment: @SudhirKGupta Scientific notations like 1.2e-1 which is 0.12

Comment: This still allows entries with multiple decimal points, such as 1.2.3.4.5

Comment: Use the `step` attribute if you don't want to allow decimal values. And concerning the letter E, [here is the link to a more complete explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31706611/why-does-the-html-input-with-type-number-allow-the-letter-e-to-be-entered-in#:~:text=HTML%20input%20number%20type%20allows,also%20be%20written%20as%202e5.)

Comment: This also works for `v-text-field`, cool!

Comment: This has been deprecated? Doesn't seem to work in Vue2 app.

Answer (score 39):

This was my solution.  Most of the answers here have been deprecated. Additionally, input values always return a string, even if you key a number.  So because of that, some of the solutions here did not work for me.

In my case I didn't want a decimal point, but I added that into the array for the purpose of this thread.

```html
<b-form-input v-model.number="quantity" @keypress="isNumber($event)" type="number"></b-form-input>
```

```js
isNumber (evt: KeyboardEvent): void {
    const keysAllowed: string[] = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '.'];
    const keyPressed: string = evt.key;
    
    if (!keysAllowed.includes(keyPressed)) {
           evt.preventDefault()
    }
}
```

Comment: My favorite answer, however, is written in TypeScript.

Comment: this should be the main answer. most of rest answers uses `event.keyCode` which is depracted

Comment: I notice `Backspace` and `Arrows` keys cannot be typed this way

Comment: As of recently, you can also detect keys like `Backspace` and `Delete` by simply adding them to that list. `event.key` supports that perfectly.

Comment: Hey! It's a pretty nice solution, but what about the copy-paste?

Answer (score 23):

Short and easy understand.

**HTML**

```
 <input @keypress="onlyNumber" type="text">
```

**VUE JS**

```
onlyNumber ($event) {
   //console.log($event.keyCode); //keyCodes value
   let keyCode = ($event.keyCode ? $event.keyCode : $event.which);
   if ((keyCode < 48 || keyCode > 57) && keyCode !== 46) { // 46 is dot
      $event.preventDefault();
   }
}
```

Comment: This way "Backspace" keypress is also not allowed. What if I want to delete previous number and add another?

Comment: You can check key code using this code
console.log($event.keyCode); //keyCodes value

Comment: How to limit the input to only one dot?

Comment: key code is deprecated

Answer (score 15):

A simple way to do this in one line:

```
IsNumber(event) {
  if (!/\d/.test(event.key) && event.key !== '.') return event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: I dont know about the performance (because of the regex), but this should the one and only answer if you are checking for numbers....

Comment: For me works `if (!/^[0-9]+$/.test(event.key) || event.key === '.') return event.preventDefault();`

Comment: `allowDecimalChars(event: KeyboardEvent) { if (/[^.0-9]/.test(event.key)) { event.preventDefault() } }`

Answer (score 12):

Here is a better way to handle the specific question asked (numbers and "dots" only) by setting v-restrict.number.decimal using the following directive. It also had some bonus code to support alpha only or alphanumeric. You could also only allow "dots" although I do not know why you would. It will not allow extra characters to "sneak through" if typing fast. It also supports copy/paste, delete, and some other keys users would expect to still work from an input:

```
Vue.directive('restrict', {
  bind (el, binding) {
    el.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
      // delete, backpsace, tab, escape, enter,
      let special = [46, 8, 9, 27, 13]
      if (binding.modifiers['decimal']) {
        // decimal(numpad), period
        special.push(110, 190)
      }
      // special from above
      if (special.indexOf(e.keyCode) !== -1 ||
        // Ctrl+A
        (e.keyCode === 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
        // Ctrl+C
        (e.keyCode === 67 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
        // Ctrl+X
        (e.keyCode === 88 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
        // home, end, left, right
        (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
        return // allow
      }
      if ((binding.modifiers['alpha']) &&
        // a-z/A-Z
        (e.keyCode >= 65 && e.keyCode <= 90)) {
        return // allow
      }
      if ((binding.modifiers['number']) &&
        // number keys without shift
        ((!e.shiftKey && (e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57)) ||
        // numpad number keys
        (e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 105))) {
        return // allow
      }
      // otherwise stop the keystroke
      e.preventDefault() // prevent
    }) // end addEventListener
  } // end bind
}) // end directive
```

To use:

```
<!-- number and decimal -->
<input
  v-model="test"
  v-ep-restrict.number.decimal
  ...
/>

<!-- alphanumeric (no decimal) -->
<input
  v-model="test2"
  v-ep-restrict.alpha.number
  ...
/>

<!-- alpha only -->
<input
  v-model="test3"
  v-ep-restrict.alpha
  ...
/>
```

This can be modified to serve as a base for just about any scenario and a good list of key codes is [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/)

Comment: I love this answer, but can it be updated to account for keyCode being deprecated?

Answer (score 8):

I solved issue like yours via vue.js filters. First i created filter - let's say  in filters.js file

```
export const JustDigits = () => {
  Vue.directive('digitsonly', (el, binding) => {
    if (/[\d\.]+/i.test(el.value)) {
      console.log('ok');
    } else {
      let newValue = el.value.replace(/[a-zA-Z]+/ig, '');
      el.value = newValue;
      console.log('should fix', newValue);
      binding.value = el.value;
    }
  });
};
```

Then in the component where this functionality is required i did:

```
import {
  JustDigits
} from './filters';

JustDigits();
```

And then you are able to use this directive in template:

```
 <input  v-model="myModel"
         v-digitsonly
         type="text"  
         maxlength="4"  class="form-control" id="myModel" name="my_model" />
```

Please note, that my regex may differ from what you need, feel free to modify it as well as this code line `let newValue = el.value.replace(/[a-zA-Z]+/ig, '');` that removes characters from the  string. I posted it just to show you one of the possible solutions vue.js provides to solve task like this.

Comment: if you type more than one letter the second one sometimes goes through.

Comment: You can avoid the fast typing extra characters getting though by wrapping the value in a half second or so debounce (importing from lodash or unserscore) before checking it

Answer (score 8):

Building on previous solutions, to prevent multiple decimal positions, also pass the v-model to the function:

`<input v-model="message" v-on:keypress="isNumber($event, message)">`

and modify the isNumber method as follows:

```
isNumber(event, message) {
  if (!/\d/.test(event.key) &&  
    (event.key !== "." || /\./.test(message))  
  )  
    return event.preventDefault();  
}
```

To limit the number of digits after the decimal add the following line into the isNumber method:

```
 if (/\.\d{2}/.test(message)) return event.preventDefault();
```

The `\d{2}` limits the entry of two digits. Change this to `\d{1}` to limit to one.

As stated in other answers, this does not prevent the pasting of non-numeric data.

Answer (score 5):

I needed my input to allow only digits, so no `e` symbol, plus, minus nor `.`. Vue seems funky and doesn't re-trigger `@onkeypress` for symbols like `dot`.

Here is my solution to this problem:

```
<input
  onkeypress="return event.key === 'Enter'
    || (Number(event.key) >= 0
    && Number(event.key) <= 9"
  type="number"
>
```

I am taking digits only, limiting from 0 to 9, but also I do want enable form submit on Enter, which would be excluded with the above approach - thus the enter.

Comment: There's a missing parenthesis in the condition, but works great! :thumbs-up:

Comment: onkeypress is deprecated now on Firefox

Answer (score 4):

You can handle this via simple html

```
<input type="number">
```

and in your **app.css**

```
/* Chrome, Safari, Edge, Opera */
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

/* this is for Firefox */
input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

Style code will remove ugly arrows from your number input field and yes it accepts dots

Answer (score 4):

@Kalimah answer didn't work for me, but I liked the idea of using regex.
In my case I needed to filter out any non-digit character, including dots.
The below code worked for me, Vue 2.6.

```html
<input type="text" v-model="variable" @input="cleanVariable" />
```

```js
methods: {
    cleanVariable(event) {
        this.variable = event.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not using an external mask lib like [vue-the-mask](https://github.com/vuejs-tips/vue-the-mask) or [cleave.js](https://github.com/nosir/cleave.js)?

For example, with **vue-the-mask** you can easily use theirs directive like this:

```
<input type="text" name="some-name" id="some-id" v-model="some.value" v-mask="'##.##.##.##.###'">
```

Comment: vue-the-mask rocks

Comment: Why not? Because you always want to minimize external libraries.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-input-only-number

```
import onlyInt, { onlyFloat } from 'vue-input-only-number';

Vue.use(onlyInt);
Vue.use(onlyFloat);

<input type="text" v-int>
<input type="text" v-float>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is `input` event which is more powerful/flexible than `keypress`, `keydown` or `change` that reacts on any type of change: program or user type such as key presses or paste events.

```js
// Initial input state
let prevValue = ''
let prevSelectionStart = 0

function allowNumbersOnly(event) {
  const input = event.target
  let value = event.target.value

  // Check if value is number
  let isValid = +value == +value

  if (isValid) {
    // preserve input state
    prevValue = value
    prevSelectionStart = input.selectionStart
  } else {
    // restore previous valid input state.
    // we have to fire one more Input event in  order to reset cursor position.
    var resetEvent = new InputEvent('input')
    input.value = prevValue
    input.selectionStart = prevSelectionStart
    input.selectionEnd = prevSelectionStart
    input.dispatchEvent(resetEvent)
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" oninput="allowNumbersOnly(event)">
```

Comment: This still allows the value `1e1` to be pasted into the input.

Answer (score 3):

Just evaluate if is nan and now you can prevent default

```
<input @keypress="isNumber">

isNumber (val) {
  if (isNaN(Number(val.key))) {
    return val.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Comment: This would be a great answer if it wouldn't also disable `delete` and `enter` keys.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with `type="number"` and `min="1"` is that it allows typing or pasting the `-` sign, the `e` sign and the `+` sign.

The problem with the `Math.abs(value)` is that it replaces the whole typed in number with `0`, which we don't want and is very frustrating.

The `e.keyCode` is very unreadable and deprecated.

The pure HTML method doesn't work in this case, you have to use JavaScript.

Remove the `type="number"` and do this:

```js
function inputNumberAbs() {
  var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
  var val = input.value;
  val = val.replace(/^0+|[^\d.]/g, '');
  input.value = val;
}
```

```html
<input oninput="inputNumberAbs()">
```

### Regex explanation:

> `^0+` removes all 0s from beginning
>
> `|` OR operator
>
> `[^\d].` remove everything that is `^`(**NOT**) a `\d`(**NUMBER**) or a
> `.`(**PERIOD**)

This prevents the user to type or paste any of the not defined characters, like `e, -, +,` and all other characters that are not numbers.

If you don't need decimal numbers just remove `.` from regex.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot find the perfect solution because some work for input but not for copy&paste, some are the other way around. Below's solution works for me. It prevents negative numbers, typing "e", copy&paste "e" text.

I use mixin so I can be reused anywhere.

```js
const numberOnlyMixin = {
    directives: {
    numericOnly: {
        bind(el, binding, vnode) {

        // console.log(el, binding);

        // this two prevent from copy&paste non-number text, including "e".
        // need to have both together to take effect.
        el.type = 'number';
        el.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
            // console.log('input', e);
            // console.log(el.validity);
            return el.validity.valid || (el.value = '');
        });

        // this prevents from typing non-number text, including "e".
        el.addEventListener('keypress', (e) => {
            let charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
            if ((charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) && charCode !== 46) {
            e.preventDefault();
            } else {
            return true;
            }
        });
        }
    }
    },
};

export {numberOnlyMixin}
```

In your component, add to your input.

```html
<input v-model="myData" v-numericOnly />
```

Comment: POTENTIAL MEMORY LEAK! Is this solution production ready? I think you need to unbind event listeners when the element leaves the DOM.

Comment: I believe creating a directive is the correct approach, although this implementation is more complex than it should be. If you're concerned about memory leaks, you can remove the listener on the directive's `unbind` event. JavaScript seems to take care of that automatically though.

Answer (score 2):

```
<v-text-field class='reqField' label="NUMBER" @keypress="isNumber($event)"></v-text-field>
methods: {
    isNumber: function(evt) {
        evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && (charCode != 9)) {
            evt.preventDefault();
        } else {
            return true;
        }
        `enter code here`
    },
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer

Answer (score 1):

I use [watcheffect()](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#watcheffect) and regex for this. This way, it works with copy-paste as well.

```
<template>
  <input type="text" v-model="data">
</template>

<script>
import { ref, watchEffect } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup() {
    const data = ref('')

    watchEffect(() => {
      data.value = data.value.replace(/[^\.0-9]/g, '')
    })

    return { data }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the number type in it:

```
<input type="number" class="yourCssClass" placeholder="someText" id="someId" />
```

and then, add the CSS required to remove the up/down spinners:

```
/* Chrome, Safari, Edge, Opera */
  input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
  input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
  }

  /* Firefox */
  input[type=number] {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
  }
```

Comment: This answer is insufficient. It doesn't handle `e` in Chromium-based browsers. Also, browsers such as Firefox don't block non numeric chars when input is type number. You can check this using MDN documentation while running Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number

Answer (score 0):

You can do it inline

```html
<input v-model="numberVar" @keypress="$event.key.match(/^[\d\.]$/) ? '' : $event.preventDefault()" />
```

or using a handler function

```html
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const numberVar = ref(0)

function handlePress(e) {
  if (!e.key.match(/^[\d\.]$/)) e.preventDefault()
}
</script>

<template>
  <input v-model="numberVar" @keypress="handlePress($event)" />
</template>
```