# Create an only numeric text field

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to build an only numeric field with VueJS. It kind of works but something is wrong:

1. **PASS:** Enter 12 in the text field, the value in VueJS is 12, the visual is 12.
2. **FAILS:** Enter 12a in the text field, the value in VueJS is 12, the visual is 12a. (expected behaviour is 12 in the text field)
3. **PASS:** Enter 12a4 in the text field, the value in VueJS is 12a4, the visual is 124

**You can try with this JSFiddle I made: https://jsfiddle.net/El_Matella/rr2qex8k/**

Here is my text field component:

```js
const TextField = {
    template: '<div><input type="text" v-model="copy"></div>',
        props: ['value'],
        data () {
        return {
            copy: null
        }
    },
    created () {
        this.copy = this.value.toString()
    },
    watch: {
        value () {
            this.copy = this.value.toString()
        },
        copy () {
            this.$emit('input', this.copy)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code that should allow me to use that text field component as an only numeric text:

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        number: 1
    },
    methods: {
        update (value) {
            this.number = parseInt(value.replace(/\D/g, ''))
        }
    },
    components: {
        TextField
    }
})
```

**The problem is that the input field does not update when the last entered char is a non numeric value. You have to enter an other numeric value in order to update the input and remove the non numeric chars.**

Comment: Hi, maybe using `type="number"` and removing the string transformations `this.copy = this.value.toString()` in created and watch will help?

Comment: It does indeed, however I would have prefer not to have the little arrows at the end of the input: https://jsfiddle.net/El_Matella/rr2qex8k/7/

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39782176/filter-input-text-only-accept-number-and-dot-vue-js/64974337#64974337

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this on your input tag

```
<input type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'/>
```

or

```
<input type="number" />
```

you can check for compatibility here:

https://caniuse.com/#search=type%3D%22number%22

Comment: This does work indeed: https://jsfiddle.net/El_Matella/rr2qex8k/15/ are the `charCode` the same on each browsers?

Comment: yes, that is ASCII related, from 48 to 57 are the codes for 0 to 9 characters, consider that with this you can't insert negative chart "-"

Answer (score 0):

You can use a getter and setter on a computed value to cleanse your input value on the way in:

```
const TextField = {
    template: '<div><input type="text" v-model="inputValue"></div>',
    props: ['value'],
    data(){
        return {
            number: 0
        }
    },
    computed: {
        inputValue: {
            get: function(){
                return this.number;
            },
            set: function(value){
                this.number = parseInt(value.replace(/\D/g, ''))
            }
        }
    }
}
```