# How does validity.valid works?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was trying to set an input number (html) to only positive numbers and I found this fine solution:

```
    <input type="number" name="test_name" min="0" oninput="validity.valid|| 
    (value='');">
```

Can anyone tell me how does *oninput="validity.valid||(value='');* works? How does it restrict the input to only positive numbers.

Thank you!

Comment: Full guide here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`min="0"` only accept numbers greater than zero. So when the user enters a value (`oninput`), either it is valid (`validity.valid`) or (`||`) the value is replaced by an empty string (`value=''`).

---

Edit:

`validity.valid` is falsy because of `min="0"` as we can see [in the doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState) under the *rangeUnderflow* property:

> "if the value is less than the minimum specified by the min attribute".

Comment: So, the `validity.valid` is related somehow to the constraint `min=0`?

Comment: Yes, as we can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState) in **rangeUnderflow**, the ValidityState is falsy 
"if the value is less than the minimum specified by the min attribute".

Comment: Oh, I see now. Thank you very much, brother, you helped me a lot there.

Answer (score 2):

This event is sent when a user enters text in a input.

This event is onlycalled when the text displayed would change, thus it is not called when the user presses non-displayable keys.

So what is does is to check the [validity.valid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState) property to make the validation.

Comment: can i ask you?. Where do you see such thing? @JuanPablo

Comment: I saw it in this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233415/how-to-make-type-number-to-positive-numbers-only/46334535#46334535?newreg=70f526a3d5e449f1ab3401824e32906f)