# How does validity.valid works in js code?

Tags: javascript

I was trying to restrict input type="number"(html) to only integers numbers, and I found this solution:

```
<input id="test" type="number" min="1" step="1" oninput="validity.valid|| 
    (value='');">
```

Can anyone tell me how can i do this in js code oninput="validity.valid||(value='')

Comment: You can read more about validity state on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState)

Comment: @evolutionxbox i already did, but i got confused when i wanted to do it in javascript, kinda don\t understand how can i do this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does validity.valid works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53697812/how-does-validity-valid-works)

Comment: @SudhirOjha well i read it, and i kinda understand how it works, but i don't understand how to do this same in js code

Answer (score 0):

This is using the Constraint Validation API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation#the_constraint_validation_api

`validity` is a property on your `input` element that returns the state: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState#properties

`validity.valid` essentially means "this is correct"

```
validity.valid||(value='')
```

is standard "or" syntax. Either take the valid result, or set the `input` `value` to an empty string

Comment: So my js code should look kinda like this, jQuery('#testTest').on('input', '#test', function () {      
         validity.valid || (value=' ') }

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation#implementing_a_customized_error_message has a good example of what you're looking for. Basicially `validity` is a property on your `input` - so it'll be something like `if(myInput.validity.valid) console.log('ok')`

Comment: if you could made example how do this this with js, i kinda still don't get it