# How to use the pattern validator to 'Add only numbers that are greater than 0'?

Tags: angular

In this form, when I add a new ingredient, it works for any number, no matter if it's positive or negative.

So, if I add 'Bread with amount 5' it will show this:

[image]

If I add 'Bread with amount -5' it will show this:

[image]

I tried to use this pattern validator: pattern="^[1-9]+[0-9]*$"

[image]

But now the 'Add' button is disabled, no matter if I want to add positive or negative numbers...

[image]

Any idea why this is not working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make type="number" to positive numbers only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233415/how-to-make-type-number-to-positive-numbers-only)

Comment: Short answer: `<input type="number" min="0">`

Answer (score 3):

You are applying Pattern on Name field.
Apply it on Number field.

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern will work. However, I think it's worth bringing up three points:

1) Most importantly, as pointed out by Mian Taimoor Tahir, you are currently applying the pattern to the wrong input.

2) That said, a simpler pattern would be:

```
[1-9]\d*
```

3) And lastly, although your question specifically mentioned "How to use the pattern validator…", I think it's worth having the same answer here in case other people are also attempting to use the pattern attribute.

That is: inputs can use `type="number"` along with the `min=1` and `step=1` parameters, also mentioned by Nicholas K.

That would look something like this:

```html
<input type="number" min="1" step="1">
```

This would be a preferable way to solve your problem for the following reasons:

- it's an easier-to-understand API for developers to update
- The browser stepper will be inserted, making it clear that this is a number input
- it will bring up a nicer keyboard for many mobile users
- it will prevent accidental, hard to see, errors such as putting the letter O in the input
- if support is a concern, more browsers (I believe) support the number input than the pattern attribute