# How to prevent user from entering negative number in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, ecmascript-6, frontend

I want to restrict users from entering negative values. I am using min = "0". With this i can restrict users from decrementing to 0, i.e, users can only decrement value till 0. But they are able to type "-". How to prevent in react js.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-input-example-forked-xnvxm?file=/src/index.js

```
<input
   type="number"
   min="0"
   step="1"                        
   onChange={this.handleChange}                        
   className="w-100"
   value= "1"
   />
```

Comment: Are you trying to make it a controlled input? Meaning its value will be set through a state variable? That also means you re-render it every time you make a change to it.

Comment: how about: if (value < 0) { return -value } ?

Comment: @codemonkey Yes...

Comment: `value={Math.max(0, this.state.inputValue)}` or do a similar calculation in `handleChange`.

Comment: Can you once take a look at this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233415/how-to-make-type-number-to-positive-numbers-only/19233458](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46334535/14055424)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handling Empty Input & Negative Numbers

```
// Converting App into Class-Component
class App extends React.Component {
  // Set State
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      number: ""
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <input
          type="number"
          min="0"
          step="1"
          onChange={(e) => {
            let val = parseInt(e.target.value, 10);
            if (isNaN(val)) {
              this.setState({ number: "" });
            } else {
              // is A Number
              val = val >= 0 ? val : 0;
              this.setState({ number: val });
            }
          }}
          className="w-100"
          // Assign State
          value={this.state.number}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: really like your solution!

Answer (score 10):

You can add an `onKeyPress` listener to the input element and that will be triggered before the `onChange` and call a function that will prevent default behaviour when the minus button is pressed.

```
const preventMinus = (e) => {
    if (e.code === 'Minus') {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
};

<input               
  type="number"
  min="0"
  onKeyPress={preventMinus}
/>
```

Note that this will still allow negative values to be pasted into the input. For this, you can add an `onPaste` listener and check the clipboard data to see if it's negative and prevent the default behaviour.

```
const preventPasteNegative = (e) => {
    const clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
    const pastedData = parseFloat(clipboardData.getData('text'));

    if (pastedData < 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
};

<input               
  type="number"
  min="0"
  onPaste={preventPasteNegative}
  onKeyPress={preventMinus}
/>
```

Comment: This is a better answer than the accept answer. works for a functional component too.

Comment: Clear and concise.

Comment: Property 'clipboardData' may not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'. Did you mean 'Clipboard'? eslint shows this error. Any idea why?

Comment: onKeyPress is deprecated now. We shouldn't use it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex to validate the input before setting the state of your input and sync the input value with your state value.

```
<input
  type="number"                  
  onChange={this.handleChange}                        
  className="w-100"
  value= {this.state.inputVal}
/>

validateNumber = (value) => {
  //true for digits only.
  const regex = /^[0-9]+$/
  return regex.test(value);
}
handleChange = ({target}) => {
  const {name,value} = target;
  const {inputVal} = this.state;

  if(value === '') {
    return this.setState({inputVal:''});
  }

  if(this.validateNumber(value)) {
    this.setState({inputVal:value})
  } else {
    this.setState({inputVal:inputVal})
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use some local component state to hold the input's value and use `Math.max(0, value)` to ensure the `value` prop/attribute is a non-negative value. The input's value will be a string in the `onChange` handler so remember to coerce it back to a number value for state.

```js
function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <label>
        Try entering a negative value
        <input
          type="number"
          min="0"
          step="1"
          className="w-100"
          value={value && Math.max(0, value)}
          onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value ? Number(e.target.value) : e.target.value)}
        />
      </label>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I tried the snippet, and once the 0 is there you can't get rid of it (unless you use the up/down arrows).

Comment: @Christophe Works for me. Are you referring to not being able to backspace/delete the 0 so the input is empty?

Comment: Right! That's what I meant.

Comment: @Christophe Small tweak to allow empty string value. You should be able to delete `0` now.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="number" onKeyDown={preventNegativeValues}/>
```

//function export

```
export const preventNegativeValues = (e) => ["e", "E", "+", "-"].includes(e.key) && e.preventDefault()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out input value inside handlechange. Something like this:

```
const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    if (!isNaN(e.target.value)) {
      setValue(e.target.value);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="text"
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        className="w-100"
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-input-example-forked-kr2xc?file=/src/index.js

Comment: This still allows negative values to be copy pasted into the input box.

Answer (score 0):

Other solutions weren't working for me (I could input negative number from scrolling mouse wheel or trackpad), so I made a kind of hardcoded method:

```
onChange={function (event) {
  if (value > 0 || event.target.valueAsNumber >= 0) {
    setValue(event.target.valueAsNumber);
  }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this answer as it has alot of functionality in one.
Use `Math.sign()` it has the following possible results:
it returns 1 if the argument is positive.
it returns -1 if the argument is negative
it returns 0 if the argument is 0
it returns -0 if the argument is -0
in all other cases it returns NaN (not a number)
example
`if(Math.sign(somevalue)!=1){ console.log("please provide a valid number" }`
}

Answer (score 0):

Use this for latest react version in input field as number

```
 <input
 type="number"      
 min={0}
 step={1}
 onKeyDown={(e) => {
 if (e.code === 'Minus') {
    e.preventDefault();
    }
  }}
 />
```