# Knockout Js Regex no negative numbers

Tags: regex, knockout.js

I'm trying to find a regex code to disable negative numbers for the user input.
I'm playing around with the code abit trying to find the right one but haven't had much success.

my current code is:

```
Price: ko.observable().extend({
        required: true,
        pattern: '^[0-9].$'
    })
```

Comment: Is that period supposed to be a decimal?  Can any digits follow the decimal?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by period. it can be decimal aswell as long as its number 1 and above

Comment: You could use this useful regular expression tester: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Try `'^[0-9]+(?:[.][0-9]+)?$'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such case, Why do you need to allow user to enter minus numbers in your input field and validate the input against negative number?

Instead you can prevent the User from entering negative numbers/strings.

This uses JavaScript, but you don't have to write your own validation routine. Instead just check the `validity.valid` property. This will be true if and only if the input falls within the range.

***Solution 1:***

```html
<html>
<body>
<form action="#">
  <input type="number" name="test" min=0 oninput="validity.valid||(value='');">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

***Solution 2:***

The below solution supports to validate multiple inputs.

```js
// Select your input element.
var numInput = document.querySelector('input');

// Listen for input event on numInput.
numInput.addEventListener('input', function(){
    // Let's match only digits.
    var num = this.value.match(/^\d+$/);
    if (num === null) {
        // If we have no match, value will be empty.
        this.value = "";
    }
}, false)
```

```html
<input type="number" min="0" />
```

***Solution 3:***

I haven't tested the below solution, But this might help as well...

Either `'/^\d+$/'` OR `'^\d+$'` pattern may help you along with your current approach.

```
Price: ko.observable().extend({
        required: true,
        pattern: '/^\d+$/'
    })
```

[Original Solution and Reference here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31575496/prevent-negative-inputs-in-form-input-type-number)..

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the digit group \d

```
pattern: '^\d+\.?$'
```

This matches the following:

- The number must start at the beginning of the line
- Must consist of 1 or more digits
- Can have the character "." 0 or 1 times
- The number must end at the end of the line

Here are some examples of matches: "34", "5", "45687654", "1.", "198289."

I notice that you said you wanted to avoid negative numbers, your solution was to squish the number to the beginning and end of the line. You can also use a negative lookbehind to check that the number does not have a negative sign, such as with

```
pattern: '(?<!-)\b\d+\.?'
```

I also added a word boundary check (`\b`) so that is would not try to match the 23 in -123