# I want to accept only 1-24 in the input field and disable all other buttons. how is it possible

Tags: reactjs

This is my input field and I want to accept only 1-24 and disable all other keys. How can this be achieved in react.

```
                    <TextFieldCustom
                    placeholder="Enter checkin hours"
                    value={e.target.value}
                    onChange={onChangeHandler}
                    maxLength={3}
                    type=number
                    onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
          
                  />
```

Comment: It is not accepting maxLength as well

Comment: What is TextFieldCustom component? Can you share its code? Or is it from some library?

Comment: If the component `TextFieldCustom` is using an `<input type="number" />`, you could use the `min` and `max` attributes to set the range of accepted values.  Like `<input type="number" min="1" max="24" />`, inside of it, in order to avoid any other number (when `type` = "number").  [W3Schools link to `min` attribute docs](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_min.asp)

Comment: @Doc using min and max will still enable the user to enter negative characters

Comment: @jarivak You are right, seems it needs also some validity check.   
Basycally adds this `oninput="validity.valid||(value='');"` to the input element to cover the negative values. 
 Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31575897/13181643)

Comment: @Farid Shabanov it is custom component. I am not able to use max and min as well.

Answer (score 0):

here is the change handler of your case without specifying type="number" :

```
const [text, setText] = useState('');
  const changeHandler = (e: any) => {
    const val = e.target.value;
    if ((val >=1 && val <= 24) || val === '') {
      setText(val);
    }
  };

return (
 <TextFieldCustom
   placeholder="Enter checkin hours"
   value={text}
   onChange={changeHandler}
   onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
  />
);
```