# Negative value of MUI textField type=number on Xiaomi

Tags: reactjs, input, mobile, material-ui, frontend

is there any way to prevent entering negative values to MUI textField type=number on Xiaomi?

I use min="1",but it doesn't help in this particular case. I achieved to prevent entering negative values everywhere but on Xiaomi mobile phone.

SOLVED.
So what worked for me.

```
const handleNegativeValues = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (
      (e.nativeEvent as InputEvent).data &&
      (e.nativeEvent as InputEvent).data !== '.'
    ) {
      e.target.value =
        !!e.target.value && Math.abs(+e.target?.value) >= 0
          ? Math.abs(+e.target?.value).toString()
          : (value as string);
    }
  };

<TextField
      autoFocus
      onInput={handleNegativeValues}
      placeholder="00.00"
      size="medium"
      type="number"
      value={value}
      variant="outlined"
    />
```

here:

- value is my current value of input stored in state.
- e.nativeEvent as InputEvent).data !== '.' - I do this because I need decimal point
- reminder: the issue apeared on Xiaomi Redmi 8 pro. Checked on Xiaomi, IPhone, Samsung, desktop.

Comment: I don't have a Xiaomi phone for testing but does any solutions in [HTML number input min and max not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32936352/html-number-input-min-and-max-not-working-properly) or [Prevent negative inputs in form input type="number"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31575496/prevent-negative-inputs-in-form-input-type-number?rq=2) answer your question? If not you could also handle the logic in [onChange](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/text-field/#text-field-prop-onChange). Also it could be helpful to share your related code here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to pass the min property like that:

```
      <TextField type="number" InputProps={{ inputProps: { min: 0 } }} />
```

see https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/#components there is a small thing about some native HTML properties that are missing.