# How to preventDefault key input by using onEdit directive of primeng?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datatables, primeng

I have a scenario to only allow positive numbers in input field.So I was trying to use the onEdit directive of primeng datatable.
How to use the event object to prevent entering negative values.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a look at [ask], and how to create a [mcve]: we need to see some code you've written in order to help.

Answer (score 0):

[Possible Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34783480/2119863)

Use input type number, and set it's minimum value to zero.

Then listen to key input and allow only the pressing of numbers.

For example:

```js
// Select your input element.
var number = document.getElementById('number');

// Listen for input event on numInput.
number.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if(!((e.keyCode > 95 && e.keyCode < 106)
      || (e.keyCode > 47 && e.keyCode < 58) 
      || e.keyCode == 8)) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
  <input type="number" id="number" min="0" />
```

Comment: @user8709948 was this helpful then?