# How to avoid negative numbers in html input?

Tags: html

I have an HTML input that accepts decimal numbers starting from 0.001. The problem is when the user clicks the down arrow it starts from -0.001. How can I avoid the negative ??

```html
<input type="number" name="amount" placeholder="0.001" step="0.001"  required>
```

Comment: First result: [Google search your question](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+avoid+negative+numbers+in+html+input)

Comment: You have wonderfull attributes to set a min value...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to prevent input type="number" getting negative values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372067/is-there-any-way-to-prevent-input-type-number-getting-negative-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  [min](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-input-min-attribute/) property

```html
<input type="number" min="0" name="amount" placeholder="0.001" step="0.001"  required>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the attribute `min`:

```
<input type="number" name="amount" min="0.001" placeholder="0.001" step="0.001"  required>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6spubgjm/

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `min` attribute of `0` to fix this.

```
<input type="number" name="amount" placeholder="0.001" step="0.001" min="0" required>
```

```html
<input type="number" name="amount" placeholder="0.001" step="0.001" min="0" required>
```

Comment: user864758 has said that the start value should be 0.001, not 0.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<input type="number" name="amount" placeholder="0.001" step="0.001" min="0.001" required>
```

Comment: user864758 has said that the start value should be 0.001, not 0.

Comment: @Suboptimizer corrected it