# In Chrome why can the invalid input `1-1` be typed in an `<input type="number">`, but not `1-e`?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

In an `<input type="number">`, I can type the following invalid input in Chrome:

1. Type `11`,
2. Move the caret in the middle between both `1`s,
3. Type `-`.

However, I cannot type this invalid input:

1. Type `1e`,
2. Move the caret in the middle between the `1` and the `e`,
3. Press `-`; it won’t be typed.

But both of these values are invalid: `input.value` is the empty string.

What is the logic behind this behavior?

Example below for you to type numbers:

```js
addEventListener("input", ({ target: { value } }) => document.querySelector("p").textContent = value);
```

```html
<input type="number"/>
<p></p>
```

Comment: "Where i can read what the logic behind that?" Read the source code of the engine??

Comment: @epascarello this's is not an easy task to do. Chromium repository is huge. if you know what file or folder i should look please provide path

Comment: Okay, now the question is clear, but _why does it matter_? These are invalid inputs anyway. By the way, Firefox allows typing these characters.

Comment: @SebastianSimon  Thatk you for editing the question. I'm just curious why it work like that. Firefox allow to type all characters.

Comment: @Teemu No, both follow the standard. _“A control’s value is its internal state. As such, it might not match the user’s current input. For instance, if a user enters the word `"three"` into a numeric field that expects digits, the user’s input would be the string `"three"` but the control’s value would remain unchanged.”_ — From the definition of [value](//html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#concept-fe-value). How user agents deal with the user’s _keyboard input_ seems underspecified, but this is just a UI / UX issue that isn’t related to HTML itself.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Thanks for clarifying, the standard texts are sometimes a nightmare to read and understand.

Answer (score -2):

Change the type of input to "text" if you want to write these characters on tag p.

The E stands for the exponent, and it is used to shorten long numbers. Since the input is a math input and exponents are in math to shorten great numbers, so that's why there is an E.

It is displayed like this: 4e.

if you want to block these characters, you can do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64477931/6620900).

You can read more [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31706796/6620900) about exponential

Comment: My question is more why i can write one type of invalid number input, but not the other in number input

Comment: Simple, the "-" sign can be inserted to say "exponentiation", ie:
 1-10 is ok;
1e-10 ok;
1-e does not exist;