# Allowing only positive numbers with decimal places

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I found this neat solution to my negative numbers problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/46039201

Here it is below

```
onInput={(e)=>{
 e.target.value = !!e.target.value && Math.abs(e.target.value) >= 0 ? Math.abs(e.target.value) : null;
}}
```

But I have a bit of an issue it only allows numbers and I do require decimal places because these inputs are for currencies such as activation fee, billing amount and such. Otherwise than that the above solution works like a charm

Does anyone here have a similar solution or something that can be added to this to make it accept decimal places ?

Ive tried looking into some others but then the user can type in -1111 and it saves it even if you add `min={0}` to the input field

Comment: You can try to use `regex` to do it

Comment: @Ian Ive tried that and it still allows -1111 numbers

Comment: Valid input checking on the `input` event is not really a great idea, especially as you update the input, as you have found out.  To save you lots of headaches, just do it the proper way, and check your data on submit.   Otherwise you have issues like as you type you get `1`, `1.`, is `1.` valid?, the user was only trying to type `1.1`.. etc.  If you want to show validity as you type, that's not as bad, but updating as you type is generally clunky..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't easy for me to find a solution. In the end, what worked was a combination of a pattern and a custom attribute to store the previous value:

```js
const restricted = document.querySelector('#restricted')
restricted.addEventListener('keyup', event => {
  const value = event.target.value;
  if (!/^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]?$/.test(value) && value !== '') {
    event.target.value =  event.target.getAttribute('data-value');
  } else {
    event.target.setAttribute('data-value', value);
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="restricted">
```

Comment: This method won't always work on a `type="number"` input. FireFox for example allows users to type non numeric characters but they are not read into the value by key events and so remain in the input field, invalidating its value. It's an adequate solution for generic inputs but has to be balanced against the loss of the several useful features associated with `type=number`.

Comment: @DavePritlove that's the reason why I didn't use `type="number"`. Yes, it provides a lot of useful features, the number keyboard on mobile devices above all, but a solution that works with bot uncancelable events and `type="number"` is impossible right now

Answer (score 0):

Make use of step

```html
<input type="number" min="0" step="0.1" oninput="this.value = Math.abs(this.value)">
```

Comment: Try typing `1.1`

Comment: Problem is you cant type 1.1 it doesn't allow it but if you press up arrow then the decimals work and users are going to complain about this

Comment: Maybe if you can write it in t his way by handling the key click, and making the step as any.  
event.keyCode = 109 is '-' on numpad